# Limit opened file descriptors used by mongodb server?

Tags: mongodb, file-descriptor

Is there any way to make mongodb server to limit opened file descriptors?
I'm using wiredtiger engine and server opens at least 2 descriptors per collection. It looks like it's opened on server start or collection creation and never closed. Documentation has no configuration parameter for file descriptors.

Comment: Yes, we are also facing the similar issue on heavily loaded server, and it seems like we will have to increase "max open files" limit.